# What is the growth rate of a complexity $O{n\choose n/4}$

Tags: asymptotics

I found an algorithm that enumerates k-subsets of length n/4 for a input set of n length, having a time complexity $O{n\choose n/4}$, the algorithm fits well a problem I'm looking to solve, but I'd like to double check if I understood well its time complexity.

I plotted it for different increasing N and looks exponential (but not as bad as $2^n$ exponential)

As I don't want to do curve fitting... it is possible to simplify that expression in a way that makes possible to get a better sense of what will be its growth?

Comment: Apply the definition of binomial coefficients.

Comment: n over k = n! / (k! (n-k)!). Now lookup the Stirling formula.

Comment: @Raphael after some digging I found that the binary entropy function provides a good result $2^{H(p)n}$ where $p = 1/K$, in the case of $O{n\choose n/4}$ that maps (roughly) to $O(2^{0.811n})$, will you consider (or maybe somebody else) to develop this approach in an answer? I feel like that could be a very good alternative for people looking to know "how fast it grows" other than the Stirling approximation.

Comment: I don't think such things are strictly ontopic here. They are probably better off on [math.SE]. (Asymptotics are always borderline.)